# function call within a function return type mismatch postgres

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have done as much research as I can on this I have look at about 20 post here and many more for Google. None seem to answer my question. So here it is:
I have a function the will need the data from `cc_getbalancesfordate(theDate date)` which returns a table like this:

currency balance

EUR      1.25

USD      0.98
....

currency is a char and balance is numeric. this function returns all the rates from the table currently like 33 row.

I am trying to call this function like this:

```
SELECT  currency , balance, cc_ratecalculation(theDate,balance,currency) 
FROM cc_getbalancesfordate(theDate);
```

its output is the same but it multiplies the  balance by a rate found in another table. 
both functions work independently. if I call it like this in a function such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cc_getbalancesfordatewitheurs(theDate date) 
RETURNS TABLE(currency char, balance numeric(20)) AS $$

SELECT currency , balance, cc_ratecalculation(theDate,balance,currency) 
FROM cc_getbalancesfordate(theDate) ORDER BY currency;

$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT * 
FROM cc_getbalancesfordatewitheurs('2014-02-15'::date);
```

with that I get the error:

```
ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return record
DETAIL:  Final statement returns too many columns.
CONTEXT:  SQL function "cc_getbalancesfordatewitheurs"
********** Error **********

ERROR: return type mismatch in function declared to return record
SQL state: 42P13
Detail: Final statement returns too many columns.
Context: SQL function "cc_getbalancesfordatewitheurs"
```

So I try to add a 3rd column and it complains that the last column returns a record. I dont know how to fix this.

basicly I want it to return the data so it is in two columns currency and balance.

here is the code for the other function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cc_ratecalculation(
    thedate date, balance numeric(15), fromcurrency char
) 
RETURNS TABLE(Curency char, Balance numeric(20)) AS $$

SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT src as Exchange, rate*balance
    FROM cc_rates
    WHERE date=thedate AND src='KRA' AND "from"=fromcurrency AND "to"='BTC' 
    UNION
    SELECT src as Exchange, rate*balance
    FROM cc_rates
    WHERE date=thedate AND src='BTE' AND "from"=fromcurrency AND "to"='BTC'
    UNION
    SELECT src as Exchange, rate*balance
    FROM cc_rates
    WHERE date=thedate AND src='CRY' AND "from"=fromcurrency AND "to"='BTC'
) a;

$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

and

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cc_getbalancesfordate(theDate date) 
RETURNS TABLE(currency char, balance numeric(20)) AS $$

SELECT currency,sum(amount) 
FROM cc_getbalancesfordate_withexchange(theDate) GROUP BY currency ;

$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

and

Comment: To clerify a little more the calculation function needs the currency and balance results from cc_getbalancesfordate(theDate).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I figured out as an answer to my question.

```
DROP FUNCTION cc_getbalancesfordatewitheurs (date);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cc_getbalancesfordatewitheurs(theDate date) RETURNS TABLE(from_currency char, to_currency char, Exchange char, rate numeric(20,10),current_balance numeric(20,10), converted_amount numeric(20,10)) AS $$

 (SELECT currency AS from_currency,
(SELECT to_currency FROM  cc_getratesfordate(theDate,balance,currency)),
(SELECT exchange  FROM  cc_getratesfordate(theDate,balance,currency)),
(SELECT rate  FROM  cc_getratesfordate(theDate,balance,currency)),
```

balance AS current_balance,
    (SELECT final_balance  FROM  cc_getratesfordate(theDate,balance,currency))
     FROM cc_getbalancesfordate(theDate) WHERE currency <> 'BTC' and currency <> 'EUR') ;

```
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT * FROM cc_getbalancesfordatewitheurs('2014-02-15'::date);
```

its pretty ugly and inefficient but I only need to run this once a day so if it take a few extra milliseconds its not a problem. 
Though if someone knows a more efficient way to write this I would sure appreciate the help.

Thanks to anyone who helps.